# Implement C# equality operator from F#

Tags: f#, operator-overloading, equality

Is it possible to provide an implementation for the C# equality (==) operator in F#?

**EDIT**:

This code:

```
static member (=) (left : Foo, right : Foo) =
```

Produces the compiler warning:

`The name '(=)' should not be used as a member name. To define equality semantics for a type, override the 'Object.Equals' member. If defining a static member for use from other CLI languages then use the name 'op_Equality' instead.`

The latter part addresses what I was trying to do. Any idea why `op_Equality` is favored over simply `(=)`?

Comment: Do you want an F# function that behaves the same way as the C# equality operator? That is, using `operator ==` where available, and calling `object.Equals` if not?

Comment: I was wanting an equality operator that would be called when `==` is used from C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
type Foo() =
    static member op_Equality (left : Foo, right : Foo) =
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for [operator overloading in F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204.aspx)?

The different operators are defined in CIL, so overloading loading an operator in F# would overload it in C#, VB.NET and any other .NET language that supports that operator.

Comment: I was under the false impression that overloading `=` in F# produces different IL than overloading `==` in C#. It's still a bit quirky IMO. I've updated the question with the details.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, `op_Equality` is favored over `(=)` since the latter looks as if it ought to affect the equality operator within F#.  That is, the behavior of the following code could be confusing:

```
type T() =
  static member (=)(x:T,y:T) = true

let eq = (=) (T()) (T()) // false???
```